# How can I create a video clip from segments of an existing AVI file?

Tags: video, editing, avi

I have a `.avi` file but I only want to play part of it (the first 20 seconds, and the segment between the 120<sup>th</sup> second and the 150<sup>th</sup> second). How can I generate a new file with just those parts of the original movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/).

Comment: I'd agree with this as your requirements appear to be specific as to at what points you want to edit. The scripting language supplied with VirtualDub is ideal for this, therefore.

Comment: Also check out Avidemux, which is the same sort of thing as VirtualDub but is open-source and supports more formats. They're both great pieces of software and have the ability to copy a section of video without re-encoding it.

Comment: bobince: VirtualDub is open-source, too. As for more formats, VirtualDubMod (http://virtualdubmod.sourceforge.net/) may be worth a try if needed.

Comment: Without question, the best of the open-source software available. Once you learn the simple control buttons, it's a snap.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be AviSynth, given that your requirements appear to be very specific as to what parts of the material you want to use and not use. It appears that you already know what you want to use and not use.

Check out this good tutorial guide for AviSynth:
http://www.reghardware.co.uk/2009/06/25/beginners_guide_avisynth/