# free avi clipping program for windows?

Tags: windows, video, avi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [edit .avi movie cut](https://superuser.com/questions/92099/edit-avi-movie-cut)

I have some video files in avi format. I need to pull out clips at certain time ranges.

Are there any free apps out there that do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify your windows version, but ["Windows Live Movie Maker"](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker) works pretty decently.